# how do I sort a python list of dictionaries given a list of ids with the desired order?

Tags: python, sorting

I've got a list of dictionaries like this:

```
users = [{'id':1, 'name': 'shreyans'}, {'id':2, 'name':'alex'}, {'id':3, 'name':'david'}]
```

and a list of ids with the desired order:

```
order = [3,1,2]
```

What's the best way to order the list `users` by the list `order`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use sort with a custom key:

```
users.sort(key=lambda x: order.index(x['id']))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
users = [{'id':1, 'name': 'shreyans'},
         {'id':2, 'name':'alex'},
         {'id':3, 'name':'david'}]
order = [3,1,2]

users.sort(key=lambda x: order.index(x['id']))
```

Answer (score 3):

If the lists are really big:

```
userd = {d['id']:d for d in users}
sortedusers = [userd.get(o) for o in order]
```

This is `O(2n)`. A solution using `sort` only will be `O(n^3.log(n))` (sort is `nlogn`, finding position of every id in list is `O(n^2)`), which is clearly worse for larger lists. For smaller lists (such as 3 items), the low overhead of not creating a new data structure will make it faster; conversely if you keep sorting by new `order` specifications, the overhead of making the new dict will quickly amortise.